# JQuery выборка src у изображений и подстановка значений в стили родительского элемента

Tags: html, jquery, slider

Имеется слайдер с несколькими item.

```
        <div class="gallery__wrapper">
        <!-- .gallery__item -->
        <div class="gallery__item">
            <div class="gallery__img-wrapper js-background">
                <img src="img/gallery/gallery-7.jpg" alt="------------незаполенное описание------------" class="d-none js-image gallery__img">
            </div>
            <!-- gallery text -->
            <div class="container">
                <h3 class="gallery__title">ЗАГОЛОВОК 1 <br>заголовок</h3>
                <p class="gallery__content">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.</p>
                <button class="d-block mx-auto accent-button">сделать на заказ</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .gallery__item -->
        <div class="gallery__item">
            <div class="gallery__img-wrapper js-background">
                <img src="img/gallery/gallery-2.jpg" alt="------------незаполенное описание------------" class="d-none js-image gallery__img">
            </div>
            <!-- gallery text -->
            <div class="container">
                <h3 class="gallery__title">ЗАГОЛОВОК 2 <br>заголовок</h3>
                <p class="gallery__content">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.</p>
                <button class="d-block mx-auto accent-button">сделать на заказ</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Неважно - почему, но требуется забирать значение **src** из каждого тэга **img** и подставлять его в родительский тэг стилем **backgroun-image**.
Вот такой код я пытаюсь заставить заработать:

```
$(this).find(".gallery__item").click(function(){
var bgSrc = $('.gallery__item > .js-background > .js-image').attr('src');
 $('.gallery__item > .js-background').css('background-image', 'url("' + bgSrc + '")');
```

});

Не работает и не могу понять - как правильно выбрать. Понимаю, что это смешная проблема, но не для меня, поэтому прошу вашей помощи!
Заранее благодарю ;)

Comment: что возвращает селектор?

Comment: Это точно должно работать по клику? Или всё таки по готовности страницы / после инициализации слайдера?

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров P.S. Только что пересмотрел код - хз откуда взял .click. Задумывалось, чтобы срабатывало без участия пользователя.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский К сожалению этот приём не выбирает каждый src - тут берётся один и лепится везде

Comment: @Scor  я же проверил прежде чем дать ссылку ...

Comment: @Scor  https://jsfiddle.net/lenskyuser/3vw0hwjz/1/  я не ту  ссылку кидал

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Отлично! Немного не так, как задумывал, но работает. Благодарю! Где вам плюсик поставить?

Comment: @Scor  если хочешь меня отблагодарить выбери лучшим ответом igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).find(".gallery__item").click(function(){
  var bgSrc = $(this).find('.js-background > .js-image').attr('src');
  $(this).find('.js-background').css('background-image', 'url("' + bgSrc + '")');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.gallery__item').click(function(){
  var bgSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  $(this).find('.gallery__img-wrapper').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgSrc + ')');
})
```

```css
.gallery__img-wrapper{
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__img-wrapper js-background">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/1/1d/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C.png/300px-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C.png" alt="" class="d-none js-image gallery__img">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h3 class="gallery__title">ЗАГОЛОВОК 2 <br>заголовок</h3>
      <p class="gallery__content">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.</p>
      <button class="d-block mx-auto accent-button">сделать на заказ</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Igor В common.js